# Vue JS 2 $on executing without $emit being called

Tags: vuejs2, event-handling, lifecycle

I created a project just to test this case that was happening in my bigger project.
The situation is the following:
I have sibling components `EmitComponent.vue` and `ListenerComponent.vue` in the EmitComponent i'm emitting an event with $emit and listening to it on ListenerComponent with $on but the function is being called on mounted, even though i created it in the mounted lifecycle function with an event bind to it.

In EmitComponent i have the following code to emit an personalized event:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="$emit('clickedEvent')"></button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

And in ListenerComponent:
And in the listener component i have the following code:

```
<template>
  <div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  
  created() {
    this.$on("clickedEvent", console.log("Something"));
  },
 
};
</script>
```

App.Vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <EmitComponent></EmitComponent>
    <ListenerComponent></ListenerComponent>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ListenerComponent from "./components/ListenerComponent.vue";
import EmitComponent from "./components/EmitComponent.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    EmitComponent,
    ListenerComponent,
  },
};
</script>
```

EmitComponent:
Also tried with other parameters such as `$emit('clickedEvent', 'randomText' )` and Objects in randomValue such as `$emit('clickedEvent', { newValue: 'Foo', oldValue: 'bar' })`.

I imagined that the function was being called because of the parenthesis on the callback argument, so i also tried the following

```
<script>
export default {
  created() {
    this.$on("clickedEvent", this.myFn);
  },
  methods: {
    myFn() {
      console.log("Something");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

And like this, myFn is never called.
Also have changed the name of my events to kebab-case `clicked-event` in both instances.
How can i make the ListenerComponent call a function only when the @click emits an named event?

I solved it with using a EventBus **BUT i really want to know why this isn't working**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your handler is never called, that is the expected behavior.

In your initial version, you set the handler to the return value of `console.log()`, which is `undefined`:

```js
this.$on("clickedEvent", console.log("Something"));
```

is the same as

```js
console.log("Something")
this.$on("clickedEvent", undefined);
```

You will see the log statement when the empty handler is registered. But there is no handler that could be triggered. You probably want to do something like:

```js
this.$on("clickedEvent", () => console.log("Something"));
```

This would register a real handler, same as your second approach (tough you will probably run into issues with that when `this` is not bound when the handler is called, you probably want `this.$on("clickedEvent", this.myFn.bind(this))`).

---

However, note that in Vue, emits go from child to parent. But your components have a sibling relation:

```html
    <EmitComponent></EmitComponent>
    <ListenerComponent></ListenerComponent>
```

Your EmitComponent actually emits to your App component, not to ListenerComponent. So either move the listener into App.vue, or use EmitComponent inside ListenerComponent.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as you fire an event on component A and listen to this event on component B that is a sibling to A. So, the sibling will not be able to handle this event. If this is the case, a solution would be to emit this event on the root level (your vue instance) and listen for it there.

Just be sure to send the current scope with the event so that the listener knows who sent the event:

```
let vm = this;
vm.$root.$emit('clickedEvent', vm);
```

```
created() {
  this.$root.$on("clickedEvent", this.myFn);
},
methods: {
  myFn(scopeFromSender) {
    console.log("Something", scopeFromSender);
  },
},
```

Hope it helps in some way or another
Mike